# Get data from data picker using angular js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I download the date picker code which consist html, css and java script. Its working well. But i want to print or get the selected date from the date picker using angular js. I wrote a code that, but it prints undefined. i dn't know where i was wrong. this is my code.

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html ng-app>
  <head>
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/bootstrap.css" />
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/todc-bootstrap.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/todc-datepicker.css" />

 <script type="text/javascript"      
  src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js"></script>
 <script src="assets/js/angular.js"></script>

  <style type="text/css">
     html,body { margin: 20px; }
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
    <form class="form-horizontal" ng-controller="MyController">
       <div class="control-group">
          <label class="control-label" for="dt1">Select Date</label>
            <div class="controls">
              <div class="input-append">
                 <input class="span2" id="dt1" type="text" ng-model="selectedDate" />
                    <button class="btn" type="button" id="cal1"><i class="icon-calendar"></i></button>
                </div> 
                    <input class="btn" type="button" value="submit" ng-click="add()"> 

   </form>
</body>


  <script type="text/javascript">
      $(function() {
         $('#cal1').datepicker({ 
           autoclose: true, 
           todayHighlight: true, 
           targetInput: $("#dt1") 
    });
 });
      function MyController($scope) {

        $scope.add = function() {
        alert($scope.selectedDate);
       }
  }
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: what exactly have you tried and is not working? selected date : {{selectedDate}} isn't getting a value?

Comment: @alou i just want to print the selected data in alert box.

Comment: Try this one http://plnkr.co/edit/KLTL9sUBbB1kVpOS4tcs?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

In your controller, you will expose a function to do an alert or whatever you wish:

```
  angular.module('ng-app')
  .controller('MyController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.showInfo = function (text) { alert(text); }
  }]);
```

And you will use it with ng-bind in your html, using the scope value from your ng-model in the other input

```
  <input class="span2" id="dt1" type="text" ng-model="selectedDate" />
  <input class="btn" type="button" value="submit" ng-click="showInfo(selectedDate)">
```